# Comparing two Excel spreadsheets to highlight changes

Tags: spreadsheet, microsoft-excel-2016, file-compare

I need to compare two large, multi page spreadsheets and combine them into one spreadsheet showing the data that was in the original one and also what it was changed to in the second one?

I have Excel 2016 on PC and Office 365 Premium on Mac if that helps. It seems to be only older versions of Excel that have that function.

Please can you help #demandingboss

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [SU] is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

It is the simplest way to compare data in Excel that lets you identify cells with different values. As the result, you will have a difference report in a new worksheet.

To compare two Excel worksheets for differences, just open a new empty sheet, enter the following formula in cell A1, and then copy it down and to the right:

```
=IF(Sheet1!A1<> Sheet2!A1, "Sheet1:"&Sheet1!A1&" vs Sheet2:"&Sheet2!A1, "")
```

There are other methods of creating rules which can check for certain conditions (does cell on sheet 1 match same cell on sheet 2 etc..), you can find more information here: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/02/25/compare-two-excel-files-sheets/